# Parcel (or analog) to exchange data between Parent and Child processes

Tags: php, parallel-processing, amphp

I have a worker pool with some tasks running. Workers are using consumables they may request at any time - I wish to use Parcel for this purpose. Parcel is a very convenient way of communicating with data, but it can't be serialized and thus you can't pass it to tasks. There's also Channel, but I don't understand how to use it in more complex cases than the docs described (when you send value, receive value, and return result). How to solve my dilemma without crutches? Thanks!

Comment: This is a very high level question that I'm not certain is a good fit for this site, but I'm also not experienced with most of the technologies you've referenced, so I'll defer to others.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use something that can be serialized? There are many queues out there that rely on PHP's native serialization format, JSON, or something domain-specific.

Comment: "I have a worker pool with some tasks running" - So you have everything working, and you want to make it better? I'm not clear on that, either.